# Change the data structure

Tags: python

I have 2 lists with the same size. I want to make a new list which the combination of both of them (list of lists) in a way that elements with the same indexes would be in a list and this list would have the same index.

input example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

combined = [[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [built-in `zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> zip(a, b)
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Comment: For Python3, this returns something like: <zip object at 0x7fc53312a6c8>

Comment: @Alexander You can force the string representation using `list()`. I omit it to simplify here. Most of Python 3 list construction returns generator indeed.

Some people might think the `list` wrapper is mandatory otherwise.

Comment: For Python3 it yields a `<zip object ...>` which is a lazily-evaluated iterable. Just write `list(zip(a,b))` to force evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

This gives you the list.

```
combined = [[i,k] for i,k in zip(a,b)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip`

```
>>> list(zip(a,b))
[(1, 4), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
```

Or you want list instead of tuples :

```
>>> [[x,y] for x,y in zip(a,b)]
[[1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]
```

Answer (score 1):

this will give you list of tuples

```
combined = list(zip(a, b))
```

if you really need your elements to be lists then we can write

```
combined = list(map(list, zip(a, b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can zip them:

`list(zip(a, b))`

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [4, 5, 6]

combined = list(zip(a,b))

for i in combined:
    print(i)
```

Use zip command to combine both the list.